# Cast UISearhBar text field as UITextField for UITextFieldDelegate usage

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm trying to cast UISearchBarTextField as UITextField and declare it with UITextFieldDelegate for some purpose.
Here is the code

```
for v in searchBar.subviews{
        for view in v.subviews{
            if view.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                print("we came here")
                if let tf = view as? UITextField{
                    tf.delegate = self
                    print("we came here too")
                    break
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Although I came through all my print, but my app crash when I press the search bar for starting search.

error: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
and it bring me to AppDelegate file.

Where was I missing?
Any help will be very appreciate

edit: I think the key point is tf.delegate = self
because it works fine if I take that off, but I can't get my purpose neither

Comment: UISearchBarTextField's delegate set to UISearchBar itself internally, and the UISearchBar is using UISearchController which in your new UITextFieldDelegate (self) doesn't provide the object.

Comment: So it's mean it's impossible to do that stuff.

Comment: What's the purpose to override the delegate of an internal subview of UISearchBar? The UISearchBarDelegate can't satisfy your needs?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. The textfield have a clear button (x) and i'm trying to hide the keyboard when it is pressed. I could do that with cancel or search button pressed but that. I found the way that i mention above but it's stuck there

Comment: Many methods that I found was written by obj-c which was posted many year ago too. I start thinking that is the old way and do not work anymore